# Typo3 USER / userFunc and caching

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript

Ist there a way to set the maximal cache time for a USER object? (not sure if its really called object..)

The only thing i found was COA_GO - which is COA with user defined cache time - but the update to the latest revision is about two years old, which makes me hope that there is a similar core feature which made it obsolete... 
/optimism off
if its not possible at all an example of how to leverage Typo3's internal cache would also solve most of my problems.
just had a look at class.t3lib_cache_manager.php, and... i don't really get it... was expecting something similar to apc...

Thanks in advance for any hint or suggestion!

Comment: Probably, You could create manual hook to the cache table to empty the cache of the desired plugin manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the new cObj Cache ([Forge](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-cobjcache)) and the [blog article explaining how it works](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/typo3-individual-cobject-caching.html).

It basically registers a new stdWrap property which can contain a lifetime:

```
5 = TEXT
5 {
    cache.key = mycurrenttimestamp
    cache.tags = tag_a,tag_b,tag_c
    cache.lifetime = 3600
    data = date : U
    strftime = %H:%M:%S
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, this looks promising! 
I hope it also gets documented... I can think of what key and lifetime are for but the rest...